# How can I fill in a web form using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a question about powershell, I have a script which allows me to connect to a secure url which asks me username and password, I manage to connect, and I receive as output an html file with entries, my question is how to fill in these inputs and submit ?

Answer (score 0):

Explore the $o_response variable to check the return values. Call it by: fcn-check-site -UNAME username -UPASS password -URI secureURL

```
function fcn-check-site {
    Param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ]
        $UNAME,
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ]
        $UPASS,
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ]
        $URI
    )
    Begin {
        $s_username = $UNAME
        $s_password = $UPASS
        $s_URI      = $URI
    }
    Process {
        try {

#           Create a Web Request object. This object can have different properties/payloads attached to be sent to the URL in question.
            $o_webrequest             = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create( $s_URI )
            $o_secpasswd              = $s_password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -ErrorAction Stop
            $o_mycreds                = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($s_username,$o_secpasswd) -ErrorAction Stop

#           The connection test is to check if the login returns a 'good/ok/200' value. Hence, nothing is POST-ed. Only GET-ted.
            $o_webrequest.Method      = 'GET'
            $o_webrequest.Credentials = $o_mycreds

#           30 second timeout on the request to be made.
            $o_webrequest.Timeout     = 30000

#           This C# code makes sure that SSL certificate checks are skipped.
            try {

#               This erroractionpreference variable will STOP the compilaton errors thrown by C#.
                $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
                add-type -ErrorAction Stop -TypeDefinition @"
                using System.Net;
                using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
                public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
                    public bool CheckValidationResult(
                        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
                        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
"@

                [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $o_response = $o_webrequest.GetResponse()

                if( ( $o_response.StatusCode -eq 'OK' ) -or `
                    ( $o_response.StatusCode -eq 200  ) ) {
                    "$( $URI ) is accessible."
#                   Check the contents of $o_response to see what is returned.

                }
                else {
                    "$( $URI ) is NOT accessible. Response Status is : $( $o_response.StatusCode )"
                }
            }
            catch {
                "[ERROR] : $( $Error[ 0 ].ToString() )"
            }
        }
        catch {
            if( $Error[ 0 ].ToString() -match "Unable to connect to the remote server" ) {
                "$( $URI ) is NOT accessible."
            }
            else {
                "[ERROR] : $( $Error[ 0 ].ToString() )"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thinks your code is very helpful, i can access to my page web, but after that i receive anathore form that ask me to fill inputs, how i can do it and sent the form with post